# django add user authentification check for class-based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have lots of class-based views in my app. Most of them should be accessible only by authentificated staff users. How can I easylly add user check for lot of class-based views?

For standart function views I added decorator like this:

```
def only_staff_allowed(fn):
    '''decorator'''
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return fn(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('moderator:login'))
    return wrapped

@only_staff_allowed
def dashboard(request):
    ''' now accessible only by staff users '''
    return render(request, 'moderator/dashboard.html', {})
```

How can I do somthing similar to class-based views like this?

```
class AddressesAddList(ListView):
    template_name = 'moderator/addresses/add_list.html'
    queryset = Address.objects.filter(need_moderating=True)
    paginate_by = 100
```

Should I add some mixins or override some methods? Or can I decorate something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should decorate the dispatch method of the class-based view. See below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there are at least three ways to avoid decorating the `dispatch` method of each and every view class you want to require login for.

If you only have a few such views, you can either use that decorator in the URLconf, like this:

```
url(r"^protected/$", login_required(ProtectedView.as_view()), name="protected_view"),
```

Alternatively, and better if you have a bit more views to protect, is to use the `LoginRequiredMixin` from [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#loginrequiredmixin):

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProtectedView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

And, if you have a lot of views to protect, you should use a middleware to cover a bunch of views in one fell swoop; something along the lines of:

```
class RequireLoginMiddleware(object):
    """Requires login for URLs defined in REQUIRED_URLS setting."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = tuple([re.compile(url) for url in REQUIRED_URLS])
        self.require_login_path = getattr(settings, 'LOGIN_URL', '/accounts/login/')
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated() and request.path != self.require_login_path:
            for url in self.urls:
                if url.match(request.path):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(u"{0}?next={1}".format(self.require_login_path, request.path))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LoginRequiredMixin. This will redirect unauthenticated users to the page set.

```py
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class DashboardIndex(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/index.html'
    login_url = 'action:login' #Where you must set the page else will use default.
    raise_exception = False
```

https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#loginrequiredmixin